# pulling a random item from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, indexing

I have 12 arrays named `f1` to `f12` each with five items. I want to randomly pull one item from each array and push these into the new array `sm1`.

```
var sm1 = [];

for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
    randomPrompt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
    sm1.push("f"+i[randomPrompt]);
}
```

However, this returns a random index of `"f"+i` instead of it indexing `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, etc.

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating numeric variables like that, you should be using an array instead.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. Yes, in this case, the f1 to f12 variable names are specific to the context I'm working in and cross-reference curriculum content. Using them will allow non-coders who have to tweak this to know which bits to tweak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to accomplish what you ask.

**Example:**

```js
var myArray = {
   "f1": [1,2,3,4,5],
   "f2": [6,7,8,9,10],
   "f3": [11,12,13,14,15],
   "f4": [16,17,18,19,20]
}

var sm1 = [];
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    randomPrompt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
    sm1.push(myArray["f"+i][randomPrompt]);
}
console.log(sm1);
```

OR, If you are using code in the browser:

```js
f1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
f2 = [6,7,8,9,10];
f3 = [11,12,13,14,15];
f4 = [16,17,18,19,20];

var sm1 = [];

for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    randomPrompt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
    sm1.push(window["f"+i][randomPrompt]);
}
console.log(sm1);
```

Or use `eval()`:

```js
f1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
f2 = [6,7,8,9,10];
f3 = [11,12,13,14,15];
f4 = [16,17,18,19,20];

var sm1 = [],item;

for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    randomPrompt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
    item = eval(["f"+i][0]);
    sm1.push(item[randomPrompt]);
}
console.log(sm1);
```

Comment: thanks Ali. Very comprehensive. Appreciate you adding different versions as it helps me see other approaches. The second worked fine and most closely followed the code I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a 2-d array instead of 12 single arrays. Then it will be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Changes below line

```
sm1.push("f"+i[randomPrompt]);
```

to

```
sm1.push(eval("f"+i+"["+randomPrompt+"]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window object.

```
var sm1 = [];

for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
    randomPrompt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
    sm1.push(window["f"+i][randomPrompt]);
}
```

Comment: You can 'this' or current scope in case it is not global.

Comment: I'm actually working globally at this point in the code so this is appropriate. I appreciate your warning though @Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sm1 = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12].map(function (arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length))];   
});
```

I'd vote using 2-d array instead of named 12 single arrays though.